# Performance improvement by priorities joining the tables

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Have a performance question about joining tables in Kafka,
currently the topology defined as the following code:

```java
table1
   .leftJoin(table2, Pair::with)
   .leftJoin(table3, Pair::add)
   .join(table4, (left) -> left.getValue(0).getId() Triplet::add)
   .leftJoin(table5, Quartet::add)
   .leftJoin(table6, Quintet::add)
```

I just wanted to know if I move the **.join** before others, can be improved on the performance and speed of consuming the data? (like below code):

```java
table1
   .join(table4, (left) -> left.getValue(0).getId() Pair::with)
   .leftJoin(table2, Pair::add)
   .leftJoin(table3, Triplet::add)
   .leftJoin(table5, Quartet::add)
   .leftJoin(table6, Quintet::add)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, performance will be improved. Let assume database provider don't do other things such as automatically optimize query.

```
Way 1: A left join B left join C inner join D
1.A left join B => Full records A
2.A left join C => Full records A
3.A inner join D => Partial A


Way 2: A inner join D left join B left join C
1.A inner join D => Partial A => A1( significantly improvement here)
2.A1 left join B => Full A1 
3.A1 left join C => Full A1
```

At step 1, way 2 have reduced the number of rows in DB => less records which are used for left join B and C.

Comment: What do you mean by "database provider"? Question is about Kafka Streams

Comment: in the past, with one issue in my job, i investigated database provider ( oracle), they automatically optimize the query ... so i mention it... anyway, the join technique is the same ... Nothing is different so much ... between database or something else ... For sure about performance, you can make the stress test with huge data and see the result.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it with huge test data, then inform you.

Comment: Kafka Streams provides different options for tables, but only querying supported is linear scans or key lookup since it's a KV store. There's not much to optimize and there's no "provider" for RockDB or a Hashmap

Comment: It's strange, in any situation even though HashMap, it should be run quicker, ex: 10 million records of A. At step 1, way 1, we have still 10 millions; way 2, we only have partial of 10 millions, in ideal case 0-10k records ... less records will run quicker when left join ...